Using an Azure private endpoint for Exchange Online Relay - GCC high
We have an online only configuration in Azure GCC high. We have virtual compute.
We would like to setup an SMTP relay to be used for notifications as a trusted connection to exchange online.
I understand the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/use-connectors-to-configure-mail-flow/set-up-connectors-to-route-mail
My question:
Can I use a private connection as a connector in exchange online ? The goal is to not route the traffic publicly.
If there is a better approach that does not include routing traffic over public IPs, can you please suggest an alternative?
Note: It does not appear that Email SMTP support through Azure Communication Services is supported in GCC High tenant (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/email/email-smtp-overview)

It does not appear to be possible to route email traffic to exchange online without using a Public IP.
I ended up standing up an IIS Virtual Server in Azure and configuring it for SMTP relay. I then routed all traffic to <tenant name>.mail.protection.office365.us
On the 365 exchange side I registered a Connector from "Your organization's email server". I chose to do it by IP. And setup the appropriate Authentication to match what was configured for the "Outbound Security" section of the SMTP (Azure) Server.
This configuration allows me to send emails "anonymously" from Azure VMs through Exchange Online only.

You could refer to https://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0001480 to see if it could help.

Hi, and welcome to SF. As it stands, this does not answer the question because answer itself is not contained in it. You will get voted down for providing kinks to 3rd party answers,

This article specifically states to use the public IP
